# Android kotlin - Activity with black transparent background and SearchView with white background

Tags: android

As the title says I nedd an activity with black transparent background and a SearchView on top of it with white background and gray/custom text/icon colors.

This is what I have so far:

activity_search_input.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SearchInput">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/searchInput"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchInput"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Even though the background is set to #FFFFFF it is gray!

in manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SearchInput"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent">
</activity>
```

in styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#66000000</item> <!-- Or any transparency or color you need -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
</style>
```

How can I do that? I'm already searching since couple hours for a solution for such a minor thing! Android is absolutely horrendous!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

True testing this out was indeed a horrendous experience unless there's an easy method I'm unaware of. Here's a workaround I found for your case.

The main issue is this line `<item name="android:background">#66000000</item>` in your Translucent style, that messes up the colors which the searchView uses behind the scenes. Remove that and the background you set for searchView should be working now.

But you'll notice all the icons and textcolor remain white you will have to either individually set these with custom icons (for some reason the textColor still wouldn't change) or simply use `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` as the parent for your translucent theme.

So now your custom Translucent theme should look like below:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
</style>
```

Now since you have removed the window background from theme you will need to set a background to the root layout using `android:background="#66000000"`

So your activity_search_input.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#66000000"
    tools:context=".SearchInput">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/searchInput"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchInput"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result was this

[image: final result]

Tried different ways but this felt the easiest, check if this helps you out, or maybe someone will come up with a better method.

Comment: Yes this worked, even though the background color #66000000 for the layout is getting ignored and is something like #05000000 but thats ok :D thanks!

Comment: Great, and no I don't think its getting ignored. Try setting it to something like ```#BB000000``` or so to make it darker